# How to make a user log off automatically after registering their account in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am running into a problem that is after a user goes through registering their account and based off of either being a customer or employee they will then be sent to a different controller to finish their profile. After completion of the profile i have it redirected to the roles home view which has completely different navbars. Now with that being said it just sends me back to my home view which doesn't have any navbars but the user is logged in and setup with a role. So i would like to figure out a way to after the Create method in a controller for the role to have the user have to actually log in.

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            @if (User.IsInRole("Employee"))
            {
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Employees")</li>
                </ul>
            }
            @if (User.IsInRole("Customer"))
            {
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Customers")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", "Customers")</li>
                </ul>
            }
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
```

After creating the new customer the break point bring you back to the shared _layout which is the default layout asp.net makes. It doesn't register User.IsInRole

Comment: Can you show us your code so that we can understand better about the problem and hopefully be able to find the solution also.

Comment: Should have some sort of isVerified column on your auth users table to determine if they have clicked the link in the email you've sent them. Otherwise prevent login